# Can you help me determine what section of digital signal processing discussed in this screenshot?

Tags: filters, sampling

what kind of filtering is it? How signal/noise ratio in the output mix of the duration of accumulation would look like, knowing 
 Signal/noise ratio=0.1
 ,The number of cycles of accumulation of up to 200 
 ,Limits of change in the signal/noise ratio of 0.1-3

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think, you should translate the original screenshot into English.

Second, your filter looks like a kind of moving average filter.

And finally, if I understood correctly, the signal-noise ratio will be equal to $\frac{signal_{old}}{noise_{old}} \times n$, where $n$ is the number of cycles of accumulation.